# MySQL - Separar valores de uma linha em varias linhas

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Preciso separar os valores de uma linha em varias linhas, levando em consideração que tem linha que tem até 2000 valores separados por ,

[image: Segue a imagem de exemplo]

Answer (score 1):

Consultando algumas referências para poder realizar o split de uma string no MySql, cheguei na seguinte procedure. Que irá percorre toda a tabela que você citou, desmembrar os valores da coluna "opens" e inserir em uma nova linha em uma tabela temporária.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SPLIT_COLUNA`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_fim INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE var_indice INT;
    DECLARE var_valor VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE var_valores TEXT;


    -- Cria um novo cursor com todos os registros da tabela 
    -- cujo a coluna queremos separar os valores em linhas.
    DECLARE var_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            opens
        FROM
            valores;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET var_fim = TRUE;

    OPEN var_cursor;


    -- Tabela temporária que irá guardar os valores separadamente.
    CREATE temporary TABLE resultado(OPEN VARCHAR(255));


    -- Percorre cada linha para obter a string que iremos dividir.
    LEITURA_COLUNAS: LOOP
        FETCH var_cursor INTO var_valores;
        SET var_indice = 0;

        -- Aqui ocorre a mágica. Realizando o split da string.
        SPLIT_COLUNA: LOOP
            SET var_indice = var_indice + 1;

            SET var_valor = REPLACE(
                SUBSTRING(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(var_valores, ",", var_indice),
                    LENGTH(
                        SUBSTRING_INDEX(var_valores, ",", var_indice - 1)
                    ) + 1
                ),
                ",",
                ''
            );

            IF var_valor = '' THEN
                LEAVE SPLIT_COLUNA;
            END IF;

            INSERT INTO resultado VALUES(var_valor);
        END LOOP SPLIT_COLUNA;

        IF var_fim THEN
            LEAVE LEITURA_COLUNAS;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Encerra o cursor.
    CLOSE var_cursor;

    -- Exibe todos os dados da tabela temporária.
    SELECT * FROM resultado;

    -- Excluimos a tabela temporária para liberar recurso.
    DROP temporary TABLE resultado;
END
```

**Como o split foi realizado**

Vamos supor que a coluna "opens" de uma determinada linha possua o seguinte valor "12345:US,56789:BR,98765:US".

Primeira rodada var_indice = 1.

```
SET var_indice = 0; -- Índice inicia com zero

SPLIT_COLUNA: LOOP
    SET var_indice = var_indice + 1; -- var_indice = 1

    SET var_valor = REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING(
            -- Corta a string(12345:US,56789:BR,98765:US) até a 
            -- ocorrência da primeira vírgula. Resultado: "12345:US".
            -- Somente está linha já erá suficiente para obter o primeiro
            -- valor. As demais irei explicar quando o loop for para 
            -- segunda posição.
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(var_valores, ",", var_indice), 
            LENGTH(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(var_valores, ",", var_indice - 1)
            ) + 1
        ),
        ",",
        ''
    );

    IF var_valor = '' THEN
        LEAVE SPLIT_COLUNA;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO resultado VALUES(var_valor);
END LOOP SPLIT_COLUNA;
```

Segunda rodada var_indice = 2.

```
SET var_indice = 0;

SPLIT_COLUNA: LOOP
    SET var_indice = var_indice + 1; -- var_indice = 2

    -- O replace esta aqui caso a string possua uma vírgula ao final.
    -- Assim removendo a mesma.
    SET var_valor = REPLACE(
        -- Portanto aqui realizamos o corte da parte que não queremos.
        -- Ficando SUBSTRING("12345:US,56789:BR", 9)
        -- Pegando parte da string após o nono carácter.
        -- Resultado: 56789:BR
        SUBSTRING(
            -- Corta a string(12345:US,56789:BR,98765:US) até a 
            -- ocorrência da segunda virgula. Resultado:"12345:US,56789:BR".
            -- Repara que o primeiro valor retornou junto desta vez.
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(var_valores, ",", var_indice), 
            -- Portanto temos que eliminar o primeiro valor.
            -- Obtendo o tamanho da string que foi resultada abaixo 
            -- somamos mais um para eliminar a virgular que está após o valor. 
            -- Resultado: 8 + 1 = 9.
            LENGTH(
                -- Obtém os valores anteriores que já guardamos.
                -- Corta a string até a última virgula que realizamos a leitura.
                -- Resultado: "12345:US"
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(var_valores, ",", var_indice - 1)
            ) + 1
        ),
        ",",
        ''
    );

    IF var_valor = '' THEN
        LEAVE SPLIT_COLUNA;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO resultado VALUES(var_valor);
END LOOP SPLIT_COLUNA;
```

**Resultado**

Tabela com os dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado procedure

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Referências**

[MySql – Criar função tipo SPLIT / Create function with SPLIT delimited strings](http://www.gnial.com.br/gnialhelp/mysql-criar-funcao-tipo-split-create-function-with-split-delimited-strings/)

[MySQL Split String Function](https://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)